Python 2.7: difference between codecs.open(<f>, 'r', encoding=<enc>) and <string>.encode(<enc>)
What is the difference between code like this:
with codecs.open(<file path>, 'r', encoding='my_enc') as f:
    json.load(f)
string = json['key']

and code like this:
with open(<file path>, 'r') as f:
    json.load(f)
string = json['key'].encode('my_enc')

There must be differences since the first doesnt work for my application, but I dont understand why exactly. I feel some misunderstanding of how this encoding stuff works.
I am using Python 2.7 and cannot update it since I receive this environment and I am limited by this.

The primary difference is the codecs.open always opens the file in binary mode. Your problem, though, seems to be that you aren't specifying the correct encoding to open, like you do with codecs.open.

What “doesn’t work”. Make a [mcve] and show what you expect, what you get, and complete error tracebacks if any
